# Irregular Polygon Sub-division?

Tags: python, recursion, polygon, shapely, bin-packing

I have a problem in which I have an irregular polygon shaped container which needs to be sub-divided such that it contains certain smaller rectangles of specific dimensions. I have previously tried addressing this problem using a bin packing approach which seems to be too time consuming. As a result I wanted to try out sub-division based approaches where the algorithm ensures that the sub-division contains certain smaller rectangles of specific dimensions while the remaining space can be considered as empty space. Any suggestions on fast algorithms for the generation of these sub-divisions preferably using the shapely library?

The irregular polygon container would look some thing like the diagram below. The edges of the container will always be right angles and it is known that items to be packed can all fit in to the given container with additional remaining free space. The constraints are the same as regular bing packing where the items should not overlap and all items should be completely within the container. The items can be rotated (preferably at right angles).

[image]

Comment: If you're asking a question it's best to indicate that through the use of a question mark (?) at the end of a properly worded question. This will make it more clear what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: I have re-worded the question. Hopefully it is much clearer now.

Comment: Thanks, @user1234. Is it possible for you to provide a representative test problem, perhaps with the dimensions of the rectangles and the coordinates of the shape you want to fit them into?

Comment: Could you clarify: do the edges of your "bin" always meet at right angles (it's rectilinear)? Can the rectangles you want to pack in it be rotated? Can the rectangles you want to pack overlap? Do the rectangles you want to pack always complete fill the "bin"?